# Karma: 'require' is not defined

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine, chai

My angular test environment was running just fine until a week ago when I started getting this error whenever I tried to run karma:

```
Chrome 53.0.2785 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
  Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
  at node_modules/chai-as-promised/lib/chai-as-promised.js:2
```

This error first occurred in the CI platform. It only started to happen in my local environment when I cleaned and reinstalled all my app's dependencies so I can conclude that some dependency got an update and now something is missing.

I found found similar issues that recommended adding extra dependencies such as `requirejs` and `browserify` to the node dependencies list as well as to the karma config file but they didn't help.

What else could be causing this error? I have the following plugins loaded to karma:

```
    plugins: [
        'karma-jasmine',
        'karma-mocha',
        'karma-chrome-launcher',
        'karma-chai',
        'karma-chai-as-promised',
        'karma-jquery-chai',
        'karma-mocha',
        'karma-coverage',
        'karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor',
        'karma-ng-json2js-preprocessor',
        'karma-sinon',
        'karma-sinon-chai'
    ]
```

Comment: This error simply indicates that requirejs is required to add there... i would suggest requirejs file in  your solution and add them to load order as welll

Comment: I tried adding it but it didn't work. I stated that as one of the things I tried...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that chai-as-promised 6.0 [dropped support for SystemJS](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised/releases/tag/v6.0.0), so the way that karma-chai-as-promised pulls in chai-as-promised no longer works.

I ended up removing karma-chai-as-promised and manually hooking up chai-as-promised in a common test initialization file: `chai.use(chai-as-promised)`.

Comment: Thanks. I downgraded chai-as-promised for the time being but will look into your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks this is such a pain since sinon has problems i requirejs is in there.

Comment: @ecc to which version did you downgrade chai-as-promised?

Comment: I don't remember, probably the one before v6?